# Sliding menu bar is over-riding ViewPager tabs. How to stop that from happening?

Tags: android

I'm using this library for my Sliding Menu. https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

My biggest problem with this is that, I'm using a ViewPagerIndicator. Thus, say I've three tabs that I've added to the viewpager, in which I've inflated 3 fragments, Tab1, Tab2, Tab3.

While swiping from right to left, I go from Tab1 to Tab2. While Swiping from left to right at Tab1, the sliding menu opens.

But say I'm in tab2, and I swipe from left to right. This should open up tab 1 and not the sliding menu, which it does here.

In my BaseActivity, this is the code I've added:

```
    menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    //menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    //menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
//  menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.base_layout);


    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

How do I stop the slide menu to slide when I'm not in Tab1?

Answer (score 2):

You should check out its provided sample app, sample always gives you great unexpected solutions.

```
yourViewPagerIndicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) { }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) { }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
                break;
            default:
                getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This answer must be choosen as correct. Thanks @Chor WaiChun

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can stop slide menu by call `getSlidingMenu().setSlidingEnabled(false);` when you in Tab layout